# is there any way to add commas in long numbers using MS flow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, office-365-developer, microsoft-flow

I have a requirement like i have to add a comma in long numbers in the email body with the microsoft flow. I have googled it I couldn't able to find the proper solution. any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no built-in function to do this. I ended up building a Flow to do numeric formatting. The Flow uses the HTTP Request trigger so I can call it from other Flows.

It's actually a pretty complex Flow so I'll just describe the basic process. I split the integer part from the decimal part and then I loop through the integer part (as a string) character by character starting from the right. After every third character I inject a comma until I hit the end of the string. Finally I combine the updated integer part with the decimal part and return the result back to the caller.

You might be able to do something similar with an expression but I haven't figured out an elegant way to do so.